# Responsive bubble effect using divs and tailwindcss

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am building a graphic pattern using divs and circular background fill (absolutely ignoring DRY principles here!) to fill a section of the screen with bubbles, some of which will eventually become buttons.

I am having an issue where resizing the screen will hide the bubbles, thus if I have buttons on the right side, they will not appear. Is there a way to adapt the scaling depending on the screen, if recommended?

Home.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from "../style";
import Bubbles from './Bubbles';

const Home = () => {
  return (
...
<div className='flex flex-auto'>
        <Bubbles />
    </div>
...
)
}
```

Bubbles.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from '../style'

const Bubbles = () => {
  return (
        <div className='flex flex-none'>
            <div className='flex-auto w-32 h-32 pattern-dots pattern-white pattern-bg-transparent pattern-opacity-60 pattern-size-2  rounded-full' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-8 h-8  rounded-full -mx-9 bg-green-700 bg-opacity-50 ' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-96 h-96  rounded-full -mx-80 my-16 bg-orange-700 bg-opacity-50' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-40 h-40  rounded-full mx-36 my-44  bg-white ' />
            <button className='flex-auto w-80 h-80  rounded-full -mx-0 my-0  bg-green-700 bg-opacity-50 text-xl' >B1</button>
            <div className='flex-auto w-56 h-56  rounded-full -mx-32 my-96  bg-orange-700 bg-opacity-50 ' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-40 h-40  pattern-dots pattern-green-700 pattern-bg-transparent pattern-opacity-60 pattern-size-2  rounded-full' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-3 h-3  rounded-full  my-96  bg-green-700 bg-opacity-50 ' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-5 h-5  rounded-full -mx-44 my-32  bg-orange-700 bg-opacity-50 ' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-32 h-32  rounded-full -mx-40 my-0  bg-orange-700 bg-opacity-50 ' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-24 h-24  rounded-full my-96  bg-green-700 bg-opacity-50 ' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-32 h-32 my-64 pattern-dots pattern-orange-700 pattern-bg-transparent pattern-opacity-60 pattern-size-2  rounded-full' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-8 h-8  rounded-full -mx-96 my-96  bg-orange-700 bg-opacity-50 ' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-9 h-9  rounded-full mx-[32rem] my-[8rem]  bg-green-700 bg-opacity-50 ' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-7 h-7  rounded-full -mx-96 my-96  bg-orange-700 bg-opacity-50 ' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-24 h-24  rounded-full mx-[40rem] my-[8rem]  bg-orange-700 bg-opacity-50 ' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-32 h-32  rounded-full -mx-[24rem] my-[2rem]  bg-orange-700 bg-opacity-50 ' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-32 h-32  rounded-full mx-[2rem] my-[16rem]  bg-orange-700 bg-opacity-50 ' />
            <button className='flex-auto w-80 h-80  rounded-full -mx-[1rem] my-[16rem]  bg-green-700 bg-opacity-50 text-xl' >B2</button>
            <div className='flex-auto w-6 h-6  rounded-full -mx-[32rem] my-[16rem]  bg-green-700 bg-opacity-50 ' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-4 h-4  rounded-full mx-[25rem] my-[24rem]  bg-green-700 bg-opacity-50 ' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-4 h-4  rounded-full mx-[25rem] my-[24rem]  bg-green-700 bg-opacity-50 ' />
            <button className='flex-auto w-96 h-96  rounded-full -mx-[44rem]   bg-orange-700 bg-opacity-50 text-xl' >B3</button>
            <div className='flex-auto w-44 h-44  rounded-full -mx-[3rem]   bg-green-700 bg-opacity-50 ' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-32 h-32 mx-[2rem] my-[7rem] pattern-dots pattern-white pattern-bg-transparent pattern-opacity-60 pattern-size-2 rounded-full' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-32 h-32 -mx-[24rem] my-[20rem] pattern-dots pattern-white pattern-bg-transparent pattern-opacity-60 pattern-size-2 rounded-full' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-20 h-20  rounded-full mx-[20rem] my-[30rem]   bg-green-700 bg-opacity-50 ' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-32 h-32 -mx-[18rem] my-[28rem] pattern-dots pattern-orange-700 pattern-bg-transparent pattern-opacity-60 pattern-size-2 rounded-full' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-2 h-2  rounded-full -mx-[3rem]   bg-green-700 bg-opacity-50 ' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-10 h-10  rounded-full -mx-[13rem] my-[29rem]   bg-green-700 bg-opacity-50 ' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-5 h-5  rounded-full -mx-[14rem] my-[30rem]   bg-green-700 bg-opacity-50 ' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-32 h-32  rounded-full mx-[36rem] my-[33rem]   bg-white  ' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-3 h-3  rounded-full my-3  bg-green-700 bg-opacity-50  ' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-4 h-4  rounded-full my-32  bg-green-700 bg-opacity-50  ' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-16 h-16  rounded-full my-96 mx-32  bg-green-700 bg-opacity-50  ' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-24 h-24  rounded-full my-3 mx-32  bg-white  ' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-80 h-80  rounded-full -mx-44 my-32  bg-green-700 bg-opacity-50' />
            <div className='flex-auto w-40 h-40  rounded-full -mx-32 my-60  bg-white  ' />



        </div>
  )
}

export default Bubbles
```

Image on large screen:
[image: Image on large screen]

Image on smaller screen:
[image: Image on smaller screen]

The bubbles on the smaller screen are truncated. Is there a way to avoid this, or maybe there is another way to do this in a more responsive manner?